# Quarkus - Spring Cloud Config Client

Tags: quarkus

I am getting this error when trying to set header that has to be sent to Spring Config Server.

```
Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.spring-cloud-config.headers" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo

# application.properties
quarkus.spring-cloud-config.headers="access_token=12345"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

`quarkus.spring-cloud-config.headers.access_token=12345`